# Running Python file uses the wrong directory? "No such file or directory" as a result

Tags: python, pandas, directory, path, anaconda

Brand new to Python, and I wrote a simple script to print some data from an Excel sheet using Pandas. I installed Pandas via Anaconda.

Weirdly when I run my .py file, ~1/4 times when I hit "Run Python File" in VSCode it gives me an error that it can't find the current .py file. The terminal shows:

```
... ~/Desktop/PSI Work/Python Data Work VSCode Project
$ Desktop/PSI Work/Python Data Work VSCode Project/dC:/Users/soup/anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Users/soup/ataWork.py"
bash: Desktop/PSI: No such file or directory
(base)
```

The filename is "dataWork.py", but for some reason it sometimes inserts the "d" in "dataWork" before the "C:" portion of the directory, breaking the path

> .../**d**C:/Users/soup/anaconda3/python.exe
> "c:/Users/soup/**ataWork**.py"

Running it again usually does the trick... but I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: reads like you're trying to parse an unquoted path with a space in it - a good solution might be "don't do that" or ensure your loading logic quotes it

Comment: Since I'm using the built-in Run Python File button in VSCode, is there a way to do the latter of what you're suggesting? Otherwise, I'll go ahead and change the folder names. I originally was not using this directory as a Python project.